# Creating a list of ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I want to create a list of ctypes.c_int32's

I have read and understand [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/unexpected-feature-in-a-python-list-of-lists).

No matter what I do, I keep creating a list of one instance of the c_int32. This works fine for int or floats or what not. Specifically I can not get ctypes to work.

```
f=[ctypes.c_int32]*10
```

but f[0] IS f[1], so...

```
f[0].value=1
```

changes f[1] as well. I know why it is doing it. How do I make it stop. That is, how do I make the list all unique instances of c_int32?

Comment: `int_10 = ctypes.c_int32 * 10` then `t = int_10()`

Comment: Aside: you're not creating *any* instances of `c_int32`.  You're creating a list of *types* (`PyCSimpleType`s, to be specific.)

Comment: DSM, Can you expand on your comment, or point to where this is explained.

Comment: @Burtski: there are no parentheses.  Compare `[int() for i in range(3)]` with `[int for i in range(3)]`.  You're basically doing the second.

Comment: I see, said the blind man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic Python mistake. To get around this you can create the list as:

```
f = [ctypes.c_int32() for i in range(10)]
```

This will do what you want. The other (cleaner) option is to create a ctypes array via:

```
f = (ctypes.c_int32 * 10)()
```